# Getting data from web api through Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Dear Experts : I am trying to get data from a web api using Angularjs But I got an error. I have tested the api through google chrome and it returns JSON correctly

First app :

```
  var contractT = angular.module("ContractT",[]);
```

Second Angular services :

```
contractT.service("crudService", function ($http)
    {
        this.getContracts = function()
        {
            return $http.get("/ContractTypesAPI/api/ContractTypes/getContracts");
        }
    }

)
```

Third Controller:

```
contractT.controller('crudController', function ($scope, crudService)
{
    loadrecords();
    function loadrecords()
    {
        var promiseGet = crudService.getContracts(); //The MEthod Call from service

        promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.Contracts = pl.data })


    }



})
```

Fourth HTML :

```
<table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>Code</tr>
                <tr>Latin Description</tr>
                <tr>Local Description</tr>
            </thead>`enter code here`
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts">
                    <td>{{c.Staff_Type_Code}}</td>
                    <td>{{c.L_Desc}}</td>
                    <td>{{c.A_Desc}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The error is :
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: c in Contracts, Duplicate key: string:f, Duplicate value: f

JSON

```
"[{\"Staff_Type_Code\":1,\"L_Desc\":\"CONTINUOUS CONTRACT AND INSURED                   \",\"A_Desc\":\"دائـــم ومـــؤمن عليـــه                          \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":12,\"L_Desc\":\"CONTRACTING 36 HOURES                             \",\"A_Desc\":\"متعــــاقد 36 ساعة                                \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":13,\"L_Desc\":\"CONTRACTING 30 HOURES                             \",\"A_Desc\":\"متعــــاقد 30 ساعة                                \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":5,\"L_Desc\":\"ASSIGNED                                          \",\"A_Desc\":\"إنتـــداب                                         \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":14,\"L_Desc\":\"متعاقد 48ساعه                                     \",\"A_Desc\":\"متعاقد 48ساعه                                     \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":15,\"L_Desc\":\"متعاقد نصف الوقت                                  \",\"A_Desc\":\"متعاقد نصف الوقت                                  \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":16,\"L_Desc\":\"الطبيب المقيم                                     \",\"A_Desc\":\"الطبيب المقيم                                     \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":17,\"L_Desc\":\"دائم و مؤمن عليه / جامعة القاهرة                  \",\"A_Desc\":\"CONTINUOS CONTRACT AND INSURED - CAIRO UNV.       \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":18,\"L_Desc\":\"CONTINUOUS CONTRACT AND INSURED WITHOUT INTENSIVE \",\"A_Desc\":\"دائم ومؤمن عليه بدون حافز                         \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":19,\"L_Desc\":\"عقود / داخلى                                      \",\"A_Desc\":\"عقود / داخلى                                      \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":20,\"L_Desc\":\"عقود /جهاز مركزى                                  \",\"A_Desc\":\"عقود / جهاز مركزى                                 \"}]"
```

The answered example on the site is not help

The API is getting data from SQL database
Any help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use track by $index

```
 <tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts track by $index">
    <td>{{c.Staff_Type_Code}}</td>
    <td>{{c.L_Desc}}</td>
    <td>{{c.A_Desc}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Duplicates should be flagged, not answered...

Comment: Thanks for replying but It returns an empty and tiny table cells in HTML page

Comment: @Hassan what do you mean? edit your question

Comment: any help , the suggested answers are helping me. Thanks lot

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: @ Sajeetharan 2 ,  no

Comment: post the json of $scope.contracts

Comment: The table has no PK, any help

Comment: "[{\"Staff_Type_Code\":1,\"L_Desc\":\"CONTINUOUS CONTRACT AND INSURED                   \",\"A_Desc\":\"دائـــم ومـــؤمن عليـــه                          \"},{\"Staff_Type_Code\":12,\"L_Desc\":\"CONTRACTING 36 HOURES                             \",\"A_Desc\":\"متعــــاقد 36 ساعة                                \"},                           \"}]"

Comment: The answers for the duplicated question are not helping me ,

Comment: any help for this issue, i am  new in Angular

Comment: Add me on Skype :sajee4ever

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat loops through a unique key. your contact list does not have a unique key that is why you are getting that error. if you do not have any unique key into contact list the you can use angular build in "track by" index option.

Comment: Thanks for replying but It returns an empty and tiny table cells in HTML page after using      <tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts track by $index">

Comment: any help, i have added the  "track by" index but it return empty data

Comment: any help because i didnt solve the problem